# Scrapy | Performance - Need to reorder URLs based on domain?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

Working on crawler which checks hundreds of websites and for every website hundreds of pages.

I found a really big performance bottleneck.

I have set a delay for domains so I'm sure that crawler doesn't send many requests to one website in short time.

But here is a problem (at least I think it is the problem):

When spider extract many urls from one domain, it filles the queue with these urls. If the number of urls at the end of the queue is bigger than number of `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`, spider ends up crawling just one website - one by one url of this website.

What I need is to be able to enqueue urls from another domains so it can use it's potential and doesn't have to wait until all urls of one website are requested.

My solution:

I think multiple queues could help. If there were separate request queue for every domain, spider could alternate the queues and wouldn't have to wait but I can't figure out how to do that.

```
class MainSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'main_spider'
    allowed_domains = []
    max_depth = 2

    example_start_urls = [
        'example.com','example2.com','example3.com']


    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.example_start_urls:
            domain = extract_dom(url)
            self.allowed_domains.append(domain)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_item, meta={'domain': domain, 'depth': 0})


    def parse_item(self, response):
        depth = response.meta['depth']
        d = response.meta['domain']
        # DO SOMETHING
        if not depth >= self.max_depth:
            extractor = LinkExtractor(allow_domains=d.name)
            links = extractor.extract_links(response)
            for link in links:
                yield scrapy.Request(link.url, callback=self.parse_item, meta={'domain': d, 'depth': depth + 1})
```

**EXPLANATION ON EXAMPLE**

Let's say `CONCURENT_REQUESTS` is set to 2. If crawler founds 20 links on `example1.com` website and `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 1`, it ends up scraping `urls` of this website one by one because there are 20 `urls` of this website enqueued. Instead of that, spider could alternate `example1.com` urls and `example2.com` urls so the process would be two times faster.

How to do that?